# Mysql "UPDATE" isn't doing anything

Tags: php, sql, mysql

This is my code for the update:

```
$key = $skills[$ind];
echo "\t\t<td>" . $key . "</td>\n";

//explode using a comma as a delimiter
$data_n = explode(",", $word);
$score[$key][”Rank”] = $data_n[0];
$score[$key][”Level”] = $data_n[1];
$score[$key][”Exp”] = $data_n[2];

echo "\t\t<td>" .$data_n[0] . "</td>\n";
echo "\t\t<td>" .$data_n[1] . "</td>\n";
echo "\t\t<td>" .$data_n[2] . "</td>\n";

$result = mysql_query("UPDATE accounts SET $key ='$data_n[1]' WHERE username = '$user'") 
          or 
          die(mysql_error());
```

Basically, there's a string "key" that is the name of the thing I'm trying to update, but it's just not updating. I've changed "mysql_query" to "print" and it prints out exactly what it's supposed to:

```
UPDATE accounts SET Total ='1144' WHERE username = 'derekboy'
```

There aren't any errors. printing out $result shows that it's "True" that it sent the message to MySQL. Can anyone see the problem, because I've been looking for a whole day and still nothing.

All of my code is located [here](http://pastebin.com/h8MGtwuL); thanks. You can see that I connect to a database at the very top of the script.

Comment: Is you mysql connection setup?

Comment: Try executing the query directly in a MySQL client.  Does it work there?

Comment: Please give us all your code. I can't tell if you selected a database, let alone connected to the MySQL server at all.

Comment: Alright, I uploaded it to pastebin.

Comment: It's been days, hours upon hours of Googling, and I still haven't found the answer.

Answer (score 1):

1) You does not seem to have connected to mysql. Does your code do `mysql_connect` and `mysql_select_db` prior to this ?

2) Try running the query in the PHPMyAdmin (or whatever MySQL client you use) to see if there's any error or not. Does the query runs fine there ?

3) Most probably, there is no `username` with value `derekboy` in your table.

Comment: I put "UPDATE accounts SET Total ='1144' WHERE username = 'derekboy'" into phpMyAdmin and it does exactly what it's supposed to. It is connected to a database though. I edited the OP with my code.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know PHP particularly well, but it seems that you are surrounding the variables with single quotes, in which variables aren't interpolated.

Try something like:

```
$result = mysql_query("UPDATE accounts SET " . $key . " ='" . $data_n[1] . "' WHERE username = '". $user" . "'") or die(mysql_error());
```

Comment: MySql doesn't care about single quotes around numbers

Comment: No, I mean PHP and substituting the variables for their values in the string sent to MySQL.

Comment: I just checked that, and it doesn't work either. I have no clue what the problem is. Like I said, if I delete "mysql_query" and replace it with "print" it shows exactly what I need SQL to get, and if I copy and paste that into phpMyAdmin it does exactly what it's supposed to.

Comment: Hmm, I don't really know what the problem is. Try prefixing the mysql_query with an @ sign maybe. I've seen it used like that before, although I'm not entirely sure what it does. Alternatively, you could try using something like the Zend framework that makes it easier to query databases.

Comment: @alpha123 - he is doing it correctly as far as the quoting goes, and using an `@` in front of the mysql_query call simply says "call this function and ignore any errors that might occur".  Generally not a good practice.